# Error while connecting from openHAB-cloud to mongodb: MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openhab

my mongodb auth is false but it getting error
my mongodb.conf file have no authenication

```
# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default


#noauth = true
#auth = true
```

my mongodb user conf file

```
 "mongodb": {
    "hosts": ["127.0.0.1"],
    "db": "openhab",
    "user": "",
    "password": ""
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wild guess here but could it be that you should omit the user and password fields as technically you are sending user and password but they are empty strings?

Comment: yes i want to disable auth

Comment: I understand but have you tried `"mongodb": {  "hosts": ["127.0.0.1"], "db": "openhab" }` without the fields `user` and `password`

Comment: Also `#noauth = true` is commented. My guess is you want `noauth = true` without the comment hash?

Comment: yeah i tried that too

Comment: after delete of username and password fields it worked thanks

Comment: I will move the comment as an answer for others in the future. Don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty string is still parsed as a value so for you to login without auth you need to omit the user and password fields. So the correct solution is this:

```
"mongodb": {
    "hosts": ["127.0.0.1"],
    "db": "openhab"
}
```